# Stream my Videos via a web browser

Tags: video-streaming, media, freebsd

I have a Media server at home that works well with upnp on my media players and mobile computers. I tried making upnp avaialbe over the internet but it really makes me scared of people just watching my videos as upnp has no authentication.

Is there any web based application that i can put behind a passworded domain but will let me browse my directroeis and play movies directly in the browser? Or even search for movies like youtube?

I use FreeNAS 7 with a dual core AMD so it can handle transcoding but runs on a weird version of PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both lighttpd and Apache have a module for streaming H.264 video; `/usr/ports/www/lighttpd-mod_h264_streaming` or `/usr/ports/www/mod_h264_streaming` respectively.

The VLC port (`/usr/ports/multimedia/vlc`) can do [streaming](http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html) as well. It has the additional advantage that it can transcode.

Comment: i will look into that. I know HTML supports mp4(h.264) natively and you can just embed it. But I wanted to stream varios formats.. but mostly looked for transcodding so it can stream within HTML5

Comment: For transcoding I would recommend doing it once and saving the result. Both `mencoder` and `ffmpeg` could help with that. Both might need some tweaking depending on the movie.